# Что такое "расплох"?

Tags: этимология

Застигнуть врасплох - значит неожиданно застать человека, когда он того не ожидает. А что такое, вообще, "расплох", в котором его застигают?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наречие "врасплох" связано с диалектным словом полОх - испуг, также: полОх - тревога, набат, полОхало - чучело на огороде, полОхать, полОшить - мутить, волновать, тревожить.

Родственные слова: всполошить, переполох.

В словах "врасплох и переполох" приставки РАЗ и ПЕРЕ имеют значение высокой степени проявления признака, сравнить: раскрасавица.

Answer (score 3):

Наречие **врасплох** связано со следующими русскими словами : плохой, плошать, оплошать, оплошка, оплошность...
Слово *врасплох*, если мы откроем Словарь Академии Российской (1789-1794), находится именно в этом гнезде (корень **плох-**) и объясняется таким образом :

> *Въ разплохъ*, во образе наречия : нечаянно...

Застать неприятеля врасплох - заставить его *оплошать*, совершить ошибку, *оплошность*. Другими словами : человек плохо к чему-то подготовлен, тут мы его и подловим.

Comment: На форуме уже отвечали на этот вопрос, можно посмотреть еще одно мнение: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/7042/этимология-врасплох

Comment: Там участник рассуждал по своей вольной прихоти, а я взял за основу ответа мнение составителей первого нашего академ. словаря, которые поставили рядом слова *плохой, оплошность, въ расплохъ*, а вот *полохъ, взполохъ, переполохъ* находятся в совсем другом гнезде. Оснований думать иначе у меня нет. В конце концов, не *располох* же мы имеем, а *расплох*. Есть - заполошный (дурной, испуганный), а есть - оплошный (ошибочный). Семантика достаточно разнится в корнях *полох-* и *плох-*, они - не одно и то же.  
Смысл слова "врасплох" - не испуг, не тревога, а неготовность что-либо сделать хорошо.

Comment: Это сейчас слово "плохой" для нас родное и понятное, но не стоит забывать о том, что происхождение у него неясное и даже значение не сразу установившееся.
А пока (если отойти от мнения составителей академического словаря) мы имеем своеобразный треугольник: (1)Существует слово "оплох" - ошибка (по Фасмеру). (2)Существуют слова "полох, всполох и, в качестве гипотезы, располох" со значением "испуг, тревога". (3) Есть (или было) слово "расплох" со значением "неожиданный". Задача: понятие "неожиданности" связано с ошибкой или испугом? Мне кажется, что с испугом.

Comment: У Фасмера обе версии отмечены как неубедительные, к слову.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему в основе всех этих слов лежат ложе и логово. Г и Ж передаются одним знаком.
 И на ложе, и в логове существо находится в беспомощном состоянии: глаза закрыты, челюсти сомкнуты, когти спрятаны, палица в стороне, платья в гардеробе, документы в дальнем ящике. Неожиданные вторжения в ложе (в логово) в такой ситуации порождают явления, охарактеризованные в предыдущих ответах. Все эти слова - близкие родственники, как, например, забрало и забор,- видимость разная, а суть одна.